# How can an applet Read/Write files on the local file-system?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

In Java JApplet, file read and write operations did not work in webrowser. When I click "Ok" button, it should be write some file in our local path. But it shows below error. How to resolve this error?

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (
    "java.io.FilePermission" "D:/.../.html" "write")
```

Comment: *"When I click "Ok" button, it should be write some file in our local path."*  What 'Ok' button?  Do you mean you have digitally signed the code, and that when the browser loads the applet, you are prompted to accept/allow the digitally signed code?  Pretend we are not psychic or looking over your shoulder at the screen of your PC.

Comment: As an aside, what is the size and nature of the information in this file?  Please be as specific as practical (privacy allowing).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson like a shark in the oceanarium :-) I think that you frightened the life out of her/him :-)

Comment: @Rishi please follows suggestion by Andrew Thompson,

Comment: @mKorbel *"like a shark in the oceanarium"*  ;)  My methods are strange, but my intent is good.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? The whole point of this community is to share your findings, not just come here for answers and ditch off.

Answer (score 7):

By default whenever a applet tries to access local resources, its denied as a part of security layer. You have following options if you need to access using applet:

1. Sign your applet using any signing mechanism and then publish,
2. (
   though this one is not a useful and recommended way of doing this.)Change the security settings on the computer where the applet is executing.

Comment: Yea i too agree that doesnt make any sense changing security settings at every client browser , but i just want to post available options :)

Comment: The link is dead now.

Comment: Removed the Deadlink from the answer