# Running my swing program on a browser

Tags: java

I'm doing my academic project currently. Its based on swings and awt. I am running it in command prompt. Is there any possibility for me to run it on a browser

Comment: You could try to convert to an applet, your client computer have to install java plugin, besides it's no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First Suggestion is to use Applets. If that is not confortable for you and if you have a simple Swing application, I would recommend that you look at [AjaxSwing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/)

I onced used it on a simple Application and it works.
Webstart is another Way to go. You have Options to take, pick the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

In order to run a Java application in a browser, you need to make it (or wrap it) in an [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html).  A Swing application is actually usually designed as a *desktop* application (meaning, standalone).  Applets tend to be pretty resource-intensive for your user.

Comment: @user3498446 For that, see the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10102327/1435657  As a side note, you should mention those kinds of requirements in your original post.  It's always good to include more details so that we can help better. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should create an applet probably, that could run in a browser.

An applet can have GUI part too similar to a desktop GUI app.
The GUI of the applet can be based on Swing or AWT.

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) which will allow you to deploy your application *as is* without any redevelopment of the code.

Comment: Cool.  I've never heard of this.  Deployment looks hard, though.  +1

Comment: It's fairly straightforward once you follow the steps plus a number of advantages, updates for new jars, Javascript interaction, more professional